# Why can't I use captureNetworkTraffic(""); with IE

Tags: java, selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver

I use

```
String trafficOutput = selenium.captureNetworkTraffic("json");
```

to get the response header from the browser. I can do this with Firefox or Google Chrome (both have responseheader), but with Internet Explorer, nothing is returned.

Any idea how I can do this with IE? I'm using IE9.

Comment: Maybe that browser doesn't support the functionality. Bear in mind this was an experimental feature that was dropped in Selenium 2 / WebDriver. It's only available in Selenium RC so is no longer a supported feature. Just stick with FF and Chrome if you can when using the feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The functionality was a hack which was implemented for Firefox in Selenium 1.  You shouldn't use this at all (or the Selenium 1 API) if you are using Selenium 2.

Instead have a look a the BrowserMob Proxy - http://bmp.lightbody.net

It's a proxy implementation so will work with all browser drivers and will be much more useful than the Selenium 1 hack implementation.